# Carbon Damage on bridge, repair possible? If so, what steps are needed?

Tags: frames, repair, carbon

This is a follow up question to:
[Attachmentpoint rim brakes carbon bike, sratches/crack?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/89949/attachmentpoint-rim-brakes-carbon-bike-sratches-crack)

So. My bridge on my x lite 4 seems to be delaminating. Unfortunately Rose does not want to honor their six year claim of frame warranty in a reasonable way.
My question now is what to do:
Can this be fixed by carbon repair? If so, what scale of repair are we talking about? What would the steps of such repair be?

I already contacted a few companies but unfortunately the response times are up to 2 weeks in my area and I need to know if I need to look for a replacment bike right now.
Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attachmentpoint rim brakes carbon bike, sratches/crack?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/89949/attachmentpoint-rim-brakes-carbon-bike-sratches-crack)

Comment: @AdamRice That is his own initial question^^

Comment: yup, that is my initial question. The question now is: Can this be fixed with carbon repair? what would be the scale of the repair and maybe what would be needed? is this just abit opf epoxy situation or are new layeres needed etc?

Comment: Well, given the response you're getting, I'll be crossing Rose of the list of bicycle manufacturers I'd buy a bicycle from.  Even if you overtorque the brake mount to some absurd degree, the metal mounting tube bonded inside the bridge will take that the force, not the carbon fiber bridge.  Unless you overtorqued it so badly the mounting tube got distorted - which would be obvious.  In other words, there's no way you can apply a force to that bridge that wouldn't be present under normal usage - and it's falling apart anyway.  And Rose refuses to stand behind their product?  OK - behavior noted

Comment: Yeah, and I never touched this screw! Rose whats me to pay a indpendend thrid party to verfiy that it is not my fault. Are you by any chance an expert on the field? Bike Mechanic? If so, could I send your response to them? Thanks in andvance andrew

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately only the repair places can say. It needs to be inspected with tools that you don't have to make the call.

My guess is this will require replacing the whole bridge, which might not be financially prudent.

Answer (score 4):

Well i got a response from a few bike repair shops:
it is a crucial spot. The bridge would need to be replaced in total. This is not doable without the part for the repairshops.
So, frame goes in the bin. Really sad.